# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found. Codeigniter Project

Tags: php

I have a `codeigniter` which works very fine on a local machine. After uploading this project to a live server, i start getting this error

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> ```
> The page you requested was not found.
> ```

I have tried several method to resolve it but still getting the same error message.
    bellow are my files.

Below is my config.php file showing the base url of my application:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.nicebis.com/';
```

This section contains the  .htaccess File:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

This section shows my database.php file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Please what is it that i'm not doing right? I need your help
    Thanks
    Ebere

Comment: make sure file name and class name first letter is uppercase like `Home.php` has class `Home`

Comment: Which version of codeigniter you are using?

Comment: Are you sure that your server's rewrite_mode is on ? , if it's not enable and you are using ubuntu then you can type `sudo a2enmod rewrite` in terminal `ssh` and enable it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My version of Codeigniter is Version 2.2.2, also i have made all my class name are all uppercase, Yet i'm still getting the same error. I'm running it on windows not Ubuntu. I just uploaded to a live server. @Arsh, How can i check if server's rewrite_mode is on?

Comment: go to your server and create a test file (php file) and paste the below code in it and then run it , it will give you the result if rewrite_mode is on or not : 

`<?php
 if(!function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); exit; }
 $res = 'Module Unavailable';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())) 
 $res = 'Module Available';
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A mod_rewrite availability check !</title></head>
<body>
<p><?php echo apache_get_version(),"</p><p>mod_rewrite $res"; ?></p>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Arsh, I just created the file and ran it on my server, but could not see "rewrite_mode". I also searched with the key word but couldnt see it.

Comment: What did the file say ? response from file ?

Comment: @Ebere your server has rewrite_mode not installed you should install it to use codeingiter 's routings check this  link to know how you can enable it : 
https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting

Comment: @Arsh, Thanks for your prompt response and your enthusiast to help me solve this issue. I hosted this web site with a hosting company. the system is (Linux hos.hostnownow.com) and i dont no how to locate .http.conf, as specified from the link you sent

Comment: @Ebere you said you are using windows server , but the hosting is linux

Comment: Sorry for that error, It was a hosted plan package and i got that info when i ran the code you sent to me. Please do you have idea on how i can resolve this? I'm still new with this.